# phpmailer with AddAttachment and dkim, i get error : dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)

Tags: php, phpmailer, dkim

I can send email with phpmailer and dkim with pass result.
but if AddAttachment file is present , 
i got : dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)

```
<?php
 $message = "<html><head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
</head>
 <body>
 <table width='650' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
 <tr>
 <td class='style22' >TEST TEST</td>
</tr>
<td bgcolor='#0066FF' class='style22'>Description </td><td>SOME TEXT</td> 
</tr>
</table></body></html>";


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'phpmailer6/vendor/autoload.php';

$file = "phpmailer6/1420069.pdf";
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->setFrom('contact@mydomain.fr', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('paul25241@gmail.com', 'Paul');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
$mail->msgHTML($message);

$mail->AddAttachment($file);      // attachment

$mail->DKIM_domain = 'mydomain.fr';
$mail->DKIM_private = 'phpmailer6/private.key';
$mail->DKIM_selector = 'default';
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "YEAR !!! Message sent!";
}



?>
```

`
authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)

Comment: DKIM signatures can encompass just the headers and not the body so perhaps this issue is related to the scope of DKIM signing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes i think so. Do you have an code sample to resolve this ?